# clear Winforms GroupBox without destroying content

Tags: c#, winforms, ironpython, groupbox

I want to clear the content of a GroupBox to fill it with new options, but I cant use the Dispose() function since I don't want to destroy the objects in it (Textboxes from another class).
Is there a way to empty a GroupBox without destroying the content?

EDIT: Since its difficult to understand what exactly I want, here is what I tried to do (this is IronPython btw, but that shouldnt be a problem)

```
def loadMethod(self, sender, e):
    self.MethodParaBox.Visible = True
    for i in self.MethodParaBox.Controls:
        self.MethodParaBox.Controls[0].Dispose()

    panel = Panel()
    panel.AutoScroll = True
    panel.Width = 150
    panel.Height = 130
    panel.Left = 25
    panel.Top = 25
    self.MethodParaBox.Controls.Add(panel)

    for i, z in enumerate(self.parent.getParameter(self.project.SelectedItem, self.design.SelectedItem)):
        if self.textBoxList[i].value.Enabled == False:
            label = Label()
            label.Left = 0
            label.Top = 30 * i
            label.Width = 80
            label.Text = z
            panel.Controls.Add(label)

            self.textBoxList[i].option3.Left = 90
            self.textBoxList[i].option3.Top = 0 + 30 * i
            self.textBoxList[i].option3.Width = 40
            panel.Controls.Add(self.textBoxList[i].option3)
```

if i call this function a second time it will throw an exception because the textbox no longer exists

Comment: what do you mean by empty then? if not removing the content?

Comment: I want the Groupbox to be empty, but not destroy the referenced content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`ControlCollection.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove.aspx)

```
foreach(Control c in groupBox.Controls()) groupBox.Controls.Remove(c);
```

Alternatively you can use [`groupBox.Controls.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx)

Comment: or just groupbox.Controls.Clear();

Comment: Nice one Phil, that should be a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`Control.ControlCollection.Clear` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx)

```
  groupBox.Controls.Clear()
```

Or [`Control.ControlCollection.RemoveAt` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removeat.aspx)

```
While groupBox.Controls.Count > 0
    groupBox.Controls.RemoveAt(0)
End While
```

Or by using For loop with Remove method

```
For i As Integer = (groupBox.Controls.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
  Dim ctrl As Control = groupBox.Controls(i)
  groupBox.Controls.Remove(ctrl)
  ctrl.Dispose()
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the groupbox contents in the design and move them away from the gb and then you can delete it safely and move back the contents as you wish.